# Calling WCF service from jsp page

Tags: asp.net, wcf, jsp

I have created a WCF Service and published it to a Windows Server running IIS. In an asp.net web application, I can add a Service Reference to the WCF Service which exposes its methods which I can call. This all works fine.

I need someone who is running a jsp site to be able to call a method in my WCF Service. How can they do that? (I know absolutely nothing about jsp). Presumably they cannot reference my WCF Service within their application in the same way you can within a .net application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web services are totally platform independent. Therefore, someone writing in Java should have no problem calling a web service server, regardless if it was written using WCF or another platform. For example, [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/), [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html) you could find some tutorials on how to build web service clients using java. This java code could be called from JSP pages.

If you want to quickly test your web service from the client side, you could use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). It's a web service client tool developed in java. I am sure you will find it useful.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I gave a java deleloper a url like:

    http://someserver/myservice/Service1.svc?wsdl

they would be able to construct a client to call my WCF?

Comment: Yes of course. Check my edited answer to see a java tool which you could use. Anyway, you should upvote my answer if you found it useful. It is very important for users navigating to your question, to be able to quickly identify helpful answers.